# Search JSON with a string and get the line number in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, javascript-objects

I have a JSON and a target string. I want to search all the keys in the JSON file for the target string and get the line number where there is a match.

```
{
  "name": "John Doe",
  "age": 30,
  "occupation": "Software Engineer",
  "address": {
    "street": "123 Main Street",
    "city": "Anytown",
    "state": "CA",
    "zip": "98765"
  },
  "phone": {
    "home": "(123) 456-7890",
    "mobile": "(987) 654-3210"
  },
  "email": "johndoe@email.com"
}
```

For example if my target string is "mobile", then it should return the 13th line.

I tried using a simple for loop but then I might need to use recursion and it will become overly complex, are there any libraries I could use?

Comment: This thread might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6946466/line-number-of-the-matched-characters-in-js-node-js

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to find the string, than count the number of new lines before it this way:

```js
let file=`{
  "name": "John Doe",
  "age": 30,
  "occupation": "Software Engineer",
  "address": {
    "street": "123 Main Street",
    "city": "Anytown",
    "state": "CA",
    "zip": "98765"
  },
  "phone": {
    "home": "(123) 456-7890",
    "mobile": "(987) 654-3210"
  },
  "email": "johndoe@email.com"
}`;
function getLine( match, search ) {
    let index = search.indexOf(match);
    let split = search.substring(0, index);
    let lines = split.split('\n').length;
    console.log( lines );
    return lines;
}
getLine( 'mobile', file );
```

Also on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/skobaljic/hm3xjeug/).

Please note, as [defined here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON):

> JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) is a standard text-based format for
> representing structured data based on JavaScript object syntax

Additionally, as commented below, to convert JSON Object into a string, kind of pretty-print with new lines and tabs, we can use JS [stringify() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify), which accepts 3 arguments:

```
JSON.stringify(obj, false, "\t")
```

Comment: Your answer is not true. `file` is not string, an object. So you can't split it with `\n`. If you make it to string using `JSON.stringify`, all `\n` is removed.

Comment: `JSON.stringify` has an [optional third parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#syntax) `space`, so if you use `JSON.stringify(file, null, 2)` for example you should get the newlines and the answer should work again.

Comment: @Adrid No one mentioned the object before you. He said `I want to search the all the keys in the JSON file`, not in JSON object. Reading the file means store the content into the string - making it a JSON object would require `JSON.parse` method. More about it you can [read here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json.asp).

Answer (score 0):

I add code below.

```
const obj = {
  name: "John Doe",
  age: 30,
  occupation: "sfd",
  address: {
    detail: {
      other1: 123,
      other2: 345,
    },
    street: "123 Maif",
    city: "Anytown",
    state: "CA",
    zip: "98765",
  },
  phone: {
    home: "(123) 456-7890",
    mobile: "(987) 654-3210",
  },
  email: "johndoe@email.com",
};

const getKeys = (object) =>
  typeof object !== "object"
    ? []
    : [
        ...Object.keys(object).reduce((keys, key) => [...keys, key, ...getKeys(object[key])],[]),
        "",
      ];
const line = getKeys(obj).indexOf("email");
```

I think it'll works as you want and can help you even a little.

Thanks.